# Saving Full Document or Just the modifications in document database

Tags: mongodb, azure-cosmosdb, document-database

Assume you have the default settings of a router, and for a certain router you want to customize some of the settings.

Which is a better way?

Save the default settings in a document inside the database and save the modification in another document or save all the configuration with the modified settings in one document?

assuming here there are many routers that have different configurations or modification of the default settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what a "router" is in this case but here are some general guidelines in making this sort of data modeling decision:

1. Because there is no cross-document join capability, you would favor a single document approach more often than you would for say a relational database.
2. You need to think about what's likely to change, in what way, and how often? So, for instance, if the defaults are likely to change than the default+difference approach might not provide any advantage. You'd have to crawl through each difference document and make sure that it specified the old default for any that you changed unless you are OK with changing your existing users settings.
3. The logic for altering settings with the single-document strategy should be simpler so that favors the single-document approach. I would think that you could even avoid the use of putting the defaults in the database at all. Just put them in your code.
4. Also, I suspect that you will be reading these configurations many times more than you'll be altering them. The single-document approach would only require one round trip to the database, so again, it's favored.

Hope that helps.